# Expo React Native App Not Showing Chart Anymore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, f2-chart

I have been using a [React Native charting library](https://github.com/aloneszjl/react-native-f2chart) for my managed Expo app with no problems for quite some time.

**Problem:** However, something might have changed since 2 months ago (August 2019) as the chart is now showing an empty space. This is true even for a simple Expo app containing just `Text` and the chart `Chart` (repo linked below).

I suspect this problem is related to React Native's WebView.

Why is the chart no longer rendering, and how can we fix this problem? Thank you!

**Repo**: https://github.com/nyxynyx/expo-f2chart-problem

**Using:**

Dev system

- expo 35.0.0
- react native 0.5.9
- react 16.8.3
- Mac OS X Mojave 10.14.6

Target Device

- Expo iOS client 2.13.0.107059
- iPhone 6S on iOS 12.4.1

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Chart from 'react-native-f2chart';

const initScript = data =>`
(function(){
    chart =  new F2.Chart({
        id: 'chart',
        pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio,
    });
    chart.source(${JSON.stringify(data)}, {
    value: {
    tickCount: 5,
    min: 0
    },
    date: {
    type: 'timeCat',
    range: [0, 1],
    tickCount: 3
    }
    });
    chart.tooltip({
    custom: true,
    showXTip: true,
    showYTip: true,
    snap: true,
    onChange: function(obj) {
        window.postMessage(stringify(obj))
    },
    crosshairsType: 'xy',
    crosshairsStyle: {
    lineDash: [2]
    }
    });
    chart.axis('date', {
    label: function label(text, index, total) {
    var textCfg = {};
    if (index === 0) {
        textCfg.textAlign = 'left';
    } else if (index === total - 1) {
        textCfg.textAlign = 'right';
    }
    return textCfg;
    }
    });
    chart.line().position('date*value');
    chart.render();
})();
`;

export default function App() {

  var data = [{
    date: "2017-06-05",
    value: 116
  }, {
    date: "2017-06-06",
    value: 129
  }, {
    date: "2017-06-07",
    value: 135
  }, {
    date: "2017-06-08",
    value: 86
  }, {
    date: "2017-06-09",
    value: 73
  }, {
    date: "2017-06-10",
    value: 85
  }];

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>My Chart</Text>
      <View style={{ height: 350, width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#555' }}>
        <Chart initScript={initScript(data)} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**Screenshot**

The darker grey area is where the `Chart` should be, but it is empty instead of showing the chart.

[image]

Comment: can you post expo snack example for the issue?

Comment: @Oleg I am trying to create an expo snack for the first time, but how do I install an npm package?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to recreate this problem with Snack, but I think there's something wrong with it because it doesn't install. So I would recommend using another module. These are already validated modules.

1. ["react-native-chart-kit"](https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit)
2. ['react-native-pure-chart'](https://github.com/oksktank/react-native-pure-chart)
3. [victory-native](https://github.com/expo/examples/tree/master/with-victory-native)

Comment: Thanks, I considered the 3 libraries you suggested, but they are lacking the features that I need (time series area chart, updates with real time data). f2chart is the only one that meets my needs

Comment: Do you think you can try to reproduce on your system instead of creating an expo snack? I am guessing this is a [RN webview issue](https://github.com/aloneszjl/react-native-f2chart/issues/10)

Comment: What about https://www.highcharts.com/blog/post/creating-mobile-charts-with-highcharts-react-native/

Comment: @Oleg Good suggestion on highcharts, it provides all the features that I need. Unfortunately, the highcharts react-native library is experiencing [some webview-related problem](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native/issues/4#issuecomment-528768184) as well, which I have yet to get working.